# Google Stackdriver API permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-iam

I am trying to get metrics using Stackdriver API, using a service account. The account has "Owner" rights on the project. I am getting the below error for all the Stackdriver API calls. Other APIs like Spanner etc I am able to use the same service account.

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User is not authorized to access the project monitoring records.
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55) ~[gax-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.setException(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:118) ~[gax-grpc-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:101) ~[gax-grpc-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:61) ~[api-common-1.2.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:492) ~[grpc-stub-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467) ~[grpc-stub-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:41) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:392) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:475) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:557) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:478) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:590) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User is not authorized to access the project monitoring records.
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526) ~[grpc-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the the service account private key json.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/subhro/workspace/7193_spanner.json"
```

The metrics I am trying to retrieve are

- spanner.googleapis.com/api/request_count
- spanner.googleapis.com/instance/storage/used_byte
- spanner.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization
- spanner.googleapis.com/instance/node_count

My gradle build has the following deps:

```
compile('com.google.guava:guava:20.0')
compile('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner:0.33.0-beta'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
compile('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-monitoring:0.33.0-beta'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
```

Has some also faced this same issue? Please help.

Comment: It seems to work for me, I'm able to read the spanner metrics listed.
With either credential file provided by `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or by gcloud sdk (`gcloud auth application-default login`). [authentication | Google Cloud Client Library for Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#authentication). Following code samples in doc [Reading Time Series](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics).

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are facing issue with Stackdriver monitoring API v3? I understand from your post you are able to execute cloud spanner successfully.   You may want to use [APIs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/troubleshooting) to debug the problem.

Comment: Yes @rkansola I am using the code snippet u pointed and setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL`. Also have tried with `application-default login`. Its the same error.

Comment: @DSaini i tried the API, I get 404. I have enabled "Stackdriver Monitoring API" from the API->Libraries and it shows up in API->Dashboard along with Spanner API.

Comment: Error 404 suggests that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. Can you please check the information you trying to access already exists? Please elaborate name of the APIs which are you trying to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the configured projectId matches your GCP project id.

On the GCP console, near top-left there is a drop-down to select your project. Then Cloud overview > dashboard > Project ID